# Crystal reports linking issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I have 2 columns, they are both patient numbers. One is defined as a string
and the other is defined as Float, null. So the link is not working. What must I do to the one defined as number? It comes from an excel. I have changed the cells there to text, it's showing this change when I upload to SQL Server, but Crystal reports sees it as a number and it won't link on the string column.

I thought to add a column to the table then copy in the contents, is that the way to go?

```
 ALTER TABLE  [Programmer].[dbo].['Preventive Care-Colon Cancer Sc']
ADD PatNum datatype nvarchar(50)
```

Comment: You can try out this.i am not sure if we can link to formula.Create a formula and in crystal report and convert the string to number and then try to link.

Comment: if you have few tables then instead of linking tables directly write query by mentioning linkings as joins